# PhpStorm 7 @method bug or I'm wrongly using phpDocumentor annotations?

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpdoc, phpdocumentor2

I don't know if this is my bad (wrong phpDocumentor annotations) or it's a bug. Anyone experiencing this issue?

```
namespace Bar\Baz;

/**
 * @method Foo baz(boolean $baz)
 */
class Foo
{

}
```

As you can see there is no code completion for chaining (i.e. `$f->baz()->baz()`) and `boolean` type is namespaced:

[image: Problem 1] [image: Problem 2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue in PhpStorm 7.x.

If you use the fully qualified name chaining and type hinting **will** work.

Reference: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-17404

Comment: *"As for the boolean type hint..."* -- it's supported in `@method` -- you need to properly declare parameters somehow, right?

Comment: @LazyOne, do you have a reference? It doesn't seem to work, and I can't find any documentation about it.

Comment: What exactly does not work? What documentation you want to see? PHPDoc one -- https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md ; http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/method.html

Comment: I understand, but what I mean is that there is no (or at least I can't find it) documentation about PhpStorm supporting these kind of type hints for @method

Comment: Well .. this page ( https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/viewing-phpdoc-comments.html ) tells us that *"PhpStorm recognizes inline documentation created in accordance with the PHP Documentation format."* PhpStrom docs never stated what tags are supported and how -- they always just show the link to PhpDocumentor website, which would suggest that they do support most of the PHPDoc tags.

Comment: Ah okay, in that case it's a PhpStorm bug :). Because it's not working, see: http://postimg.org/image/hex8rnkq3/ and http://postimg.org/image/ti2kf7vsb/

Comment: Of course it's a bug -- you have said it yourself in your own answer :) . The solution -- use FQN here as well (e.g. `\bool` instead of `bool`)